# How to submit angular 6 form to another page [not api] and receive data from .

Tags: angular6

i.e,  want to submit data to  external url and after submitting data external url should open and . and from external url i will receive data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are vary ways to do this. I'm not giving you code or example of that. Because you will get easily by search. I just give you ways to do that.

**Solution 1:**

You can store data in cookie and read cookie in any component.

**Solution 2:**

Make a service and in service make public variable. Import service in component and store data in variable. Now you can access that variable into other component.

**Solution 3:**

Use the angular feature of passing data between component's to components. Just do some R&D on that you will get easily required stuff to do that.

For more details with example read this [link](https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb).

Hope it will help you...

Comment: @Kamran Maqbool Have you able to pass data now ?